# .htaccess rewrite rule to add a string in the middle of the URL

Tags: apache, drupal, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Using a .htaccess rewrite rule, I need to add "?q=" before the path on any URL's containing the word "imagecache"

Therefore, if the URL is:

```
http://mysite.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/myimage.jpg
```

...then it will really try:

```
http://mysite.com/?q=sites/default/files/imagecache/myimage.jpg
```

But that will ONLY happen if the URL contains "imagecache." Otherwise, it does no rewriting.

Also, this will only happen if /sites/default/files/imagecache/myimage.jpg isn't already an existing image file. I believe I can do that using:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

...right? It's just the first part that I can't figure out.

Comment: Doesn't Drupal already do this? The rewriting part, I mean.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm having a weird issue where ImageCache URL's that aren't already generated images are returning 404 rather than generating the images...presumably due to some caching thing going on on the server. So this is my attempt to get around that.

Comment: Is that where the request is processed before Imagecache can generate the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*imagecache.*)$ /?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^mysite.com/(.*)/imagecache/(.*)$ mysite.com/?q=$1/imagecache/$2
```